# Is this a photo of a rough sleeper who froze to death?

Tags: united-kingdom, photography

[image]

The caption reads:

> This picture is a picture of a DEAD homeless man who has froze to death on our streets , in Leicester a few days ago ,not one mention in the media about it and you are probably thinking why is Nigel posting a pic like this ?.....well here is why ....I for one am sick to the back teeth of every time I turn on the TV there is some twat of an actor asking us to donate money overseas , to Sudan, water aid, kids in somalia , Muslim aid the list goes on , for us to help others ,who's governments spend ££££ on wars & weapons , we supposed to be the 5th richest country , yet I see pictures like this , an utter utter disgrace, know one should be homeless in this country regardless of their problems , it seems we are being brainwashed by the media , how about helping people born here first !!!!!!!! Rant ova feel free to share

[The Metro has an article about a homeless man found dead due to the cold](http://metro.co.uk/2017/12/18/homeless-man-found-dead-sleeping-rough-freezing-cold-7168799/), but it talks about Birmingham, not Leicester.

Has this been debunked or confirmed anywhere?

Answer (score 8):

## The guy is a rough sleeper but he was not dead in that photo.

http://www.leicestermercury.co.uk/news/leicester-news/viral-facebook-post-rough-sleeper-1044114

> Leicester City Council which is responsible for preventing rough
>   sleeping in the city has had its outreach teams investigate the
>   apparent death.
>
> It says no rough sleepers have died on the streets recently.
>
> A council spokesman said: “We are aware of this post.
>
> “This has been investigated and there is no truth in the claim.”
>
> The council said it has contacted a number of groups that shared the
>   post in good faith to explain it was fake and many of them as a result
>   removed the post from their feeds.
>
> The Mercury understands the man in the picture is genuinely a rough
>   sleeper who has been begging in the city centre but that he is not
>   dead.
>
> Arif Voraji, of Help the Homeless Leicester, said: "It's fake.
>
> “A guy with right wing views then shared it and that got it spread
>   round even more - though a lot of people did challenge him and a lot
>   of the posts got taken down.
>
> “The guy in the picture is 100 per cent homeless. We know him.
>
> “He’s not dead though. We’ve seen him about.
>
> “It just goes to show how easy it is for false stuff to be shared on
>   social media and why you have to be careful with it.”

Source found using google reverse image search.